# Laravel PHPMAiler Contact Form E-mail send progress 500 Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, phpmailer

> Hi, i am using Laravel php panel. and when I try to post information to the site, 500 | I am getting a Server Error. Necessary details are below. and log records are up.Thanks.

```
(1794)*
  protected static function isShellSafe($string)
    {
        //Future-proof
        if (
            escapeshellcmd($string) !== $string
            || !in_array(escapeshellarg($string), ["'$string'", "\"$string\""])
        ) {
LARAVEL LOG FILE DETAILS:
   [2022-07-13 00:12:29]
     local.ERROR: Call to undefined function PHPMailer\PHPMailer\escapeshellcmd() {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined function PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\escapeshellcmd() at public_html/Upverse/core/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:1794)
    [stacktrace]
    
    #0 public_html/Upverse/core/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1887): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer::isShellSafe()
    
    #1 public_html/Upverse/core/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1650): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->mailSend()
    
    #2 public_html/Upverse/core/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1486): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->postSend()
    
    #3 public_html/Upverse/core/app/Http/Controllers/Front/FrontendController.php(804): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->send()
    
    
    ".env" file;

 EXAMPLE I CREATE THIS FORMAT;
   
    MAIL_DRIVER=mail
    MAIL_HOST=mail.****.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=contact@****.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Upverse/sendquote" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
(1887)* if (empty($this->Sender) && !empty(ini_get('sendmail_from'))) { //PHP config has a sender address we can use

```
    $this->Sender = ini_get('sendmail_from');
}
if (!empty($this->Sender) && static::validateAddress($this->Sender)) {
    if (self::isShellSafe($this->Sender)) {
        $params = sprintf('-f%s', $this->Sender);
    }
    $old_from = ini_get('sendmail_from');
    ini_set('sendmail_from', $this->Sender);
}
$result = false;
if ($this->SingleTo && count($toArr) > 1) {
    foreach ($toArr as $toAddr) {
        $result = $this->mailPassthru($toAddr, $this->Subject, $body, $header, $params);
        $addrinfo = static::parseAddresses($toAddr, true, $this->charSet);
        $this->doCallback(
            $result,
            [[$addrinfo['address'], $addrinfo['name']]],
            $this->cc,
            $this->bcc,
            $this->Subject,
            $body,
            $this->From,
            []
        );
    }
} else {
```

```
1650)*

public function postSend() {

    try {
        //Choose the mailer and send through it
        switch ($this->Mailer) {
            case 'sendmail':
            case 'qmail':

                return $this->sendmailSend($this->MIMEHeader, $this->MIMEBody);
            case 'smtp':
                return $this->smtpSend($this->MIMEHeader, $this->MIMEBody);
            case 'mail':
                return $this->mailSend($this->MIMEHeader, $this->MIMEBody);
            default:
                $sendMethod = $this->Mailer . 'Send';
                if (method_exists($this, $sendMethod)) {
                    return $this->$sendMethod($this->MIMEHeader, $this->MIMEBody);
                }

                return $this->mailSend($this->MIMEHeader, $this->MIMEBody);
        }
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        if ($this->Mailer === 'smtp' && $this->SMTPKeepAlive == true) {
            $this->smtp->reset();
        }
        $this->setError($exc->getMessage());
        $this->edebug($exc->getMessage());
        if ($this->exceptions) {
            throw $exc;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

```
(1486)*

        return $this->postSend();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        $this->mailHeader = '';
        $this->setError($exc->getMessage());
        if ($this->exceptions) {
            throw $exc;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
frontendcontroller.php (804)* try {

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->setFrom($from, $request->name);
        $mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $message;

        $mail->send();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // die($e->getMessage());
    }

    Session::flash('success', 'Email sent successfully!');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Most likely your hosting provider has disabled that function. Switch to sending using SMTP (which doesn't need that function), or find a better hosting provider.

Comment: @YnsKzy... Is your other video upload problem now solved? You did not reply my email suggesting to use Youtube. I wondered if you saw it first, before you go too far on a different solution. PS: This comment will be deleted soon.

Comment: Hello @VC.One Youtube Big Problem this project. I Can Made, Self Host Add subtitles and video. this video and subtitles; 


Each of the Video and Subtitles will be adjusted separately for registered users in the database. here in the user panel, videos and subtitles need to be saved according to the user's name.I need a solution like this.

Comment: I saw your message earlier but I didn't understand it enough to respond. I will try again... **(1)** _"I Can Made, Self Host Add subtitles and video"_ does "**I Can** Made" mean it is **possible for you** to make the video upload site? You got a VPS now? **(2)** _"videos and subtitles need to be saved according to the user's name"_ If you read my email again you will see, I said it is possible to move converted videos to your own storage place where you can have folders for each user (you just copy the Youtube video files and your VTT subtitle files into those user folders)

Comment: **(3)** Maybe it will be easier if you see what I mean, I will try to show you example of using Youtube if you don't have a VPS to achieve video converting. Check your email after 24 hours from now.

Comment: @VC.One Please, You Can Check Your E-mail.

THANKS BEST REGARDS

Comment: OK. I understand now. I will show you something tomorrow about "FFmpeg" converting. Just wait. Thanks

Comment: I will Wait @VC.One
Thanks
BEST REGARDS